# Draw a vertical line on Left Click MouseDownEvent

Tags: wpf, oxyplot, tracker

I'm using the Oxyplot library to plot some graphs based on real-time data. I know there is a feature called `Tracker` that shows some tooltip-like information (coordinates, for example) based on the `Position` where the user left-clicks. The information is only shown while the left-button is pressed.

I'm currently testing this functionality on a line graph, not sure if it works for other types.

What I wanted to do is to keep this info on screen and making it disapper only if the user tries to set a new one, clicking somewhere else on the graph and replacing the older information. Adding a vertical bar where the user clicked would be nice too.

I checked the Oxyplot documentation and I know that it is possible to customize this 'Tracker', but I failed to find a solution for my situation.

EDIT:

I've found [this](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/Examples/ExampleLibrary/Examples/MouseEventExamples.cs) example, it seems helpful, but I'm struggling to extract the usefulness of it. Please help!

UPDATE:

Let me go a little further on the explanation of what I'm trying to achieve. I have many graphs, each of them placed on a separated panel (or tab). If I left-click in a position of a graph, I want to show the `Tracker` info on that specific position **on each and every graph** while the user doesn't click on another position (setting a new `Tracker` and removing the old one). In other words, it is allowed one `Tracker` at a time, and this is set on every existing graph at the same X-position.

UPDATE 2:

Alright, so after giving it a thought, I decided not to maintain the `Tracker` when left-clicking. Instead, I just want **to draw a vertical line on every graph on the position of the click**. Just one line at a time is permitted, it can be treated as a "temporary marker". I believe this is more doable than the other approach and will suffice my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the left button and replace it by just hovering the mouse, almost always showing the tracker:

```
public PlotController customController { get; private set; }

customController = new PlotController();
customController.UnbindMouseDown(OxyMouseButton.Left);
customController.BindMouseEnter(PlotCommands.HoverSnapTrack);
```

Xaml:

```
<oxy:PlotView Controller="{Binding customController}"/>
```

EDIT >>>>>>

TrackerManipulator code: https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Manipulators/TrackerManipulator.cs

I think you should create a custom TrackerManipulator, and override the Complete method to not to do the "this.PlotControl.HideTracker();" line.

Comment: Alright, that works, but still it is not the behaviour I'm looking for. I'll try to update my question to explain better.

Comment: So, you want to leftclick and set a global tracker position. You have the unbind part, now you need the left click event part I suppose.

Comment: That's more like it, yes. I need to set a customTracker (or override the exisitng one) so it doesn't disapper on MouseUp and set it globally like you said.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I'll be back as soon as I finish testing it.

Comment: After messing with this suggestion, I decided this wasn't the best approach to do it. I'll update the question one more time with a new idea.